# How to derive the answer for this puzzle problem visually?

Tags: graphing-functions, puzzle

I was looking at this [problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1833/how-much-red-sand-and-how-much-blue-sand?noredirect=1#comment3348_1833) on Puzzle StackExchange about working out the proportion of sand in two separate beakers. Rather than providing a mathematical explanation, I thought it would be easiest to try and illustrate this visually, but I would like to know what the mathematical solution would be for any given size of beakers and cups. I was hoping that someone would be able to explain this relationship a little bit better, and I can come up with a diagram that will help illustrate this problem better.

The problem is also summarized here:

You have two large beakers of the same size.

- Beaker A is half filled with blue sand.
- Beaker B is half filled with red sand.

Steps:

1. You take a cup of blue sand from Beaker A and pour it into Beaker B.
2. You mix up the contents of Beaker B until the colour is consistent.
3. You take a cup of the contents of Beaker B and pour it into A.
4. You mix up the contents of Beaker A until the colour is consistent.

Which is there now more of:

- Blue sand in Beaker B or
- Red sand in Beaker A?

Comment: Physics, the Law of Conservation of Blue.

Answer (score 1):

The total amount of sand in each beaker is the same at the end as it was at the beginning.  So, whatever amount of blue sand is missing from A has left a space which must have been filled by an equal amount of red.

Therefore, the amount of blue in B at the end is the same as the amount of red in A.

Comment: Is this only because the contents are mixed evenly? Would this still hold true if you were to add another beaker with green sand into the equation?

Comment: The conditions in the question about "consistent colour" are just distractors and are completely irrelevant.  If there was little or no mixing then you could not tell exactly how much blue is missing from A, but however much it is, the space must have been filled with red.

Comment: Re: adding green, it would depend what the question is ;-)  After all, you now have (at least) six things to think about: how much blue in B, how much blue in C, how much red in A, how much red in C, how much green in A, how much green in B.

Comment: So if the question was that you took one cup of blue sand from one beaker and one cup of green sand from another beaker and mixed it evenly in the beaker with the red sand, then put one cup back in the beaker with the blue sand and one cup back in the beaker with the green sand they would all have even amounts of each colour?

Comment: Not at all.  This isn't even true with two beakers - the amount of blue in B is the same as the amount of red in A, that's not the same as saying that A has equal amounts of both colours.  In your three-beaker problem, the total amount of blue in B and C would equal the total amount of red and green in A, and you could make similar statements about the total amount of red in A and C, and the total amount of green in A and B.  Not sure these make a very interesting problem though :(